# Disable login via vnc

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, x-server

How to disable vnc? I need the authorization was only for ssh(pub_key).

Example is digitalocean vnc authorization.

Image:

[image]

To log in via vnc not going

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the service, if you are not a very experienced user I suggest you to use the tool rcconf for that.

Comment: What exactly is this service?(Shown in picture).In rcconf no problem vnc.And I don't know how to turn it off.